# Should I clone authentication tokens from cookies/localStorage to Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux

I am using [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) to save user's authentication tokens.

And as you know, it is so easy to use.

Should I clone tokens to Redux store? or just pull from cookies when need to use?

Which one is preferred for performance?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid as much security issues as possible I'd prefer using a HttpOnly cookie to store tokens. Furthermore, I think performance should not be your primary concern here, but security.
I personally think you should not spread that information even more into other storage solutions.
Although it might not be the expected answer, I still hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Benjamin. Could you explain more about "Server site cookie"? Does it mean browser cookie or something another thing?

Comment: Sorry i mean a Cookie having httponly set to true so it can not be accessed with js.